# Extracted Data Response not displaying

Tags: flutter

I have a set of data stored on Firebase which I intend to use in my Flutter App. However, right now I don't understand why the data isn't playing on the console which is what I'm trying to do. My code is as follows:

main_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../model/model.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  MainScreenState createState() => MainScreenState();
}

class MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<ModelClass>(context, listen: false).getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  void clickedButton() async {
    await Provider.of<ModelClass>(context, listen: false).getData();
    print('clicked');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Demo App"),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Click Me'), onPressed: clickedButton)));
  }
}
```

model.dart As the name suggests, this is the model class from where the API call is made.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Model {
  final String district;

  Model({required this.district});
}

class ModelClass with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, dynamic> _data = {};

  Map<String, dynamic> get data {
    return {..._data};
  }

  Future<void> getData() async {
    final url = Uri.parse('https://demoapp-2f09d-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    print(response);
    print(response.body);
    final extractedData = json.decode(response.body);
    Map<String, dynamic> temp = {};
  }
}
```

I get the below error on clicking the button. This is also the same when the data gets initialized initially.

```
I/flutter (12441): Instance of 'Response'
I/flutter (12441): <!DOCTYPE html>
I/flutter (12441): <html lang="en">
I/flutter (12441):   <head>
I/flutter (12441):   <meta charset="utf-8">
I/flutter (12441):   <meta content="width=300, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
I/flutter (12441):   <meta name="google-site-verification" content="LrdTUW9psUAMbh4Ia074-BPEVmcpBxF6Gwf0MSgQXZs">
I/flutter (12441):   <title>Sign in - Google Accounts</title>
I/flutter (12441):   <style>
I/flutter (12441):   @font-face {
I/flutter (12441):   font-family: 'Open Sans';
I/flutter (12441):   font-style: normal;
I/flutter (12441):   font-weight: 300;
I/flutter (12441):   src: url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem5YaGs126MiZpBA-UN_r8OUuhs.ttf) format('truetype');
I/flutter (12441): }
I/flutter (12441): @font-face {
I/flutter (12441):   font-family: 'Open Sans';
I/flutter (12441):   font-style: normal;
I/flutter (12441):   font-weight: 400;
I/flutter (12441):   src: url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFVZ0e.ttf) format('truetype');
I/flutter (12441): }
I/flutter (12441):   </style>
I/flutter (12441):   <style>
I/flutter (12441):   h1, h2 {
I/flutter (12441):   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
I/flutter (12441):   -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
I/flutter (12441):   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
I/flutter (12441):   -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
I/flutter (12441):   -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
I/flutter (12441):   }
I/flutter (12441):   @-webkit-keyframes fontfix {
I/flutter (12441):   from {
I/flutter (12441):   opacity: 1;
I/flutter (12441):   }
I/flutter (12441):   to {
I/flutter (12441):   opacity: 1;
I/flutter (12441):   }
I/flutter (12441):   }
I/flutter (12441):   </style>
I/flutter (12441): <style>
I/flutter (12441):   html, body {
I/flutter (12441):   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
E/flutter (12441): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 2, character 1)
E/flutter (12441): <!DOCTYPE html>
E/flutter (12441): ^
E/flutter (12441): 
E/flutter (12441): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1405:5)
E/flutter (12441): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1272:9)
E/flutter (12441): #2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:937:22)
E/flutter (12441): #3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:40:10)
E/flutter (12441): #4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:506:36)
E/flutter (12441): #5      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:157:41)
E/flutter (12441): #6      ModelClass.getData (package:demo_app/model/model.dart:23:32)
E/flutter (12441): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12441):
```

I get the instance though, but not the data. I would like to know what I can do to see the value of `extractedData`.

Comment: What appears in the console when you do `print(response.body)`? Is it JSON?

Comment: @enzo Nothing. I get the same thing as above.

Comment: Have you put the `print(response.body)` before the `json.decode` line? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70610312/edit) with the updated code.

Comment: After doing what you asked, I now get an HTML response.  Let me update the above error so that you can see it. @enzo

Comment: @enzo The ModelClass code has been updated as well.

Comment: It probably server side error, Ask your api developer to check his/her api response

Comment: The problem is that `response.body` is returning HTML, while you're expecting to return JSON. Try accessing it using [firebase_database](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database) API, which handles the JSON conversion for you.